# Open the DPI settings dialog programatically?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, dpi

I have an application which requires a huge display resolution. So it's my task to warn users who has a greater DPI than 96 (standard).

How do I open the Windows Dialog for DPI settings, so the user would be able to change it?

Comment: If the user has a good reason to use high DPI, why doesn't your app adapt to that?

Comment: Because there a way too many buttons, fields, etc. It's an application grown in about 15 years. It's nearly impossible...

Comment: What if the user has sight difficulties?

Comment: Good argument but this is one of our smallest issues... and i'm just the trainee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144191(v=vs.85).aspx .

Pre-vista you can directly invoke the control panel executable specifying the appropriate applet page to display, for vista & 7 you can simply execute `%windir%\system32\DpiScaling.exe`

Comment: Possibly you know how to call the dialog with XP? Vista/Win7 works fine.